# Netbeans webservice client works only when running from IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, java-metro-framework, wsit

Using Netbeans 6.8 and metro 2.0 I have written a simple application that makes calls to a webservice and displays the results in java swing components.  When I run the application in the Netbeans IDE (using F6), the application works perfectly.

However, when I attempt to run the compiled application from the .jar file in the dist folder, my swing UI comes up, but when I press the button that causes my web service to be called, nothing happens.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try running in a terminal window (CMD.EXE) to see if there are any exceptions printed to the console.
- Does your action listener work when stand alone?  Confirm by printing a message to System.out.